# How to trigger the autosave in Woodburrow

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

In Skylanders: Giants, you could force the autosave aboard Flynn's ship by entering any of the rooms.

Woodburrow, in Skylanders: Swap Force does not have any "rooms", per se. Entering or exiting a store, even with new purchases does not seem to trigger the autosave.

For example:

1. I completed the first mission, unlocking Woodburrow. The game autosaved at this point.
2. I repaired the Upgrade shop and made a few purchases. The game was *not* autosaved at this point.
3. I walked around the area talking to characters and did not see the autosave icon at any other point.
4. I shut the game off.
5. When I reloaded, the autosave after the first mission was loaded. The shop had not been repaired. My upgrades *were* still purchased, as they are saved to the Skylander figure and not the game. I had to re-repair the upgrade shop.

There must be some way to trigger the autosave from within Woodburrow, right?

Comment: The Skylanders-Giants tag is about as accurate as saying it's Skylanders: Spyro's Adventure, but the question is about Swap Force, not Giants.

Comment: I retagged this to the correct game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per an [Activision rep on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/skylanders/comments/1oipwr/how_do_you_autosave_in_woodburrow_swap_force/cct6h7k):

> Swap Force uses an autosave feature that is explained when the game boots up. The autosave (console) occurs when there is a Progression - Chapter Completion, Challenge Completion or picking up a Collectable.
>
> The toy saves every 30 seconds and when gaining XP, Treasure, Upgrades, Stat Boost and Hat pick up.

Based on their comment, there is no way to trigger it by entering/exiting an area of Woodburrow as there was in Giants, but [another Redditor offers the following suggestion](http://www.reddit.com/r/skylanders/comments/1oipwr/how_do_you_autosave_in_woodburrow_swap_force/ccsckd9):

> I turn subtitles on and off which triggers autosave. Still extra work but quickest I've found.

I have confirmed this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The chest that is in the room with the Chieftess and Tessa is an autosave box in Woodburrow.

Comment: The one to the left of the entrance that can only be opened once per visit?